# do i need to use 2 indexes for the same column or one is enough?

Tags: mysql, performance, indexing

I have two `SELECT` queries:

```
SELECT *
FROM `users_emails`
WHERE `user_id` = :id;
```

```
SELECT *
FROM `users_emails`
WHERE `user_id` = :id
  AND `email` = :email;
```

Do i need 2 indexes?

One for `(user_id)` and one for `(user_id, email)`, or just one for `(user_id, email)` will be enough?

table structure is:

```
CREATE TABLE `users_emails` (
  `id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `user_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `email` VARCHAR(254) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`));
```

Comment: `(user_id, email)` should be enough to cover both queries.

Comment: So, the first query could list multiple rows if a user has multiple emails?  It seems like `users` would have `user_id` as the `PRIMARY KEY`??  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE users`

Comment: @RickJames the table name is `users_emails`, sorry for the misleading..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`PRIMARY KEY` is a `UNIQUE` key is an `INDEX`.  So, it is redundant to reindex the PK.

If a user can have multiple emails, then this table is a many-to-many mapping between users and emails, and you need

```
 CREATE TABLE users_emails (
     user_id ...,
     email ...,
     PRIMARY KEY(user_id, email),
     INDEX(email, user_id)  -- in case you need to look up a user given an email
 );
```

This is really the general case -- a user may have a work and a personal email.  And/or a husband and wife may share a single email.

But...  If your application asks the user for their email, they will give you *one* email, and you won't need to know about any others?  In this case, simply include `email` in the `Users` table and don't have the many:many mapping table, nor an `Emails` table.

Comment: thanks, so in which case I need 2 or more indexes for the same column ? if there is any?

Comment: @MatanCohen - Essentially never need 2 indexes for a _single_ column.  Note that my example had the same two columns, but arranged differently -- that is useful.

Answer (score 0):

If user_id is the primary key (or is at least unique), you just need to specify this one in your query.
Doing the query with both ID and email is not wrong, is just overkill, but it could be useful if one of them is provided by userend.

Comment: What if a user has multiple email addresses?

Comment: For what I understand from the question, one user have one email. If an user can have multiple email addresses (why, btw?) you should run your query through your email table or with an "email2" column or with a `LIKE` if multiple emails are on the same column

Comment: You are right, I just assumed that the table user is something like "id, username, email, password" and most of the times "email" is a single and unique field of the table

Comment: @herkil - Your Comment disagrees with your Question -- Is there a `user_id` column?  Or an `id` column?  What is the `PRIMARY KEY`?  And now you are implying that you have either `UNIQUE(email)` or `PRIMARY KEY(email)`??

Comment: I cannot know table structure based on the answer because there is not such detail. @Nick proposed that the table might have 1 or more email addresses, but I do not know how OP handle this. Plus, like i said, if there is a single email, this is most likely to be an unique (not necessarly primary) field in the table.